# initializer for 'Stripe.StripeConfiguration' threw an exception

Tags: c#

I am trying to integrate stripe into my website, but getting this error upon initialization of "stripeconfiguration" in my production server. it works fine in my test server VC2019. I uploaded the entire BIN directory to production sever, still the same problem. Stripe support is non-existent. can anyone tell what the problem is? I suspect I am missing some assemblies or conflict in some, but don't know which one?
thanks
here is my code: ( this is just a simple test code)

```
enter code here
var secretKey = "sk_test_51IPeD8*********************";

StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = secretKey;---->> this throws the error
lblMsg.Text = StripeConfiguration.ApiVersion;
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the exact same problem. The problem lies in NewtonSoft.Json in my case. Make sure that the version in your project and on production matches. Also, there must be dependentassembly tag in your local project web.config. You will need to copy over those to the web.config as it mentions newtonsoft version reference.
There is still something missing as I am still stuck, but this might lead you to the answer. If not, try upgrading to NewtonSoft.Json version 12.
It worked in my case, but I can't take it to production because my actual website needs Newtonsoft version 10

Comment: I got the problem resolved after many trials and errors. you are partially right, newtonsoft is the one of many issues. first you must upgrade to at least .net 4.6, then after upgrading to latest newtonsoft, there are many other assemblies and dll's that also need to be upgraded. is a royal mess. too bad stripe does not mention any of these issues in their dev portal.

Comment: Thanks @codeZila. Could you possibly list the other assemblies I could upgrade? My .NET version is already up to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm it has to do with Newtonsoft.Json. In order to fix this, you need to:

- Check which version of package you have in your project ("Manage NUGet Packages for Solution"), in my case: 13.0.1
- Find the binary "Strong Name" version, which you can obtain by downloading "NUGet Package Explorer" from the microsoft store, click on "Open package from online", search for "Newtonsoft.Json", clicking on "show all versions" on the right, double click on "13.0.1", open "lib" on the right, "net45" (the framework I'm using), double click on "Newtonsoft.Json.dll", and find that "strong name" which in my case is "13.0.0.0".
- Take note of the "PublicKeyToken" (it's on the top, under "Full Name"), which in my case is 30ad4fe6b2a6aeed.
- Get back to Visual Studio project, open web.config, and put it like this.

  ```
   <runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
  ```
- in case you just updated from previous Newtonsoft.Json, you could still find the previous "old" version there (12.0.0.0), so you just need to change it.
- check that you don't have any duplicate bindingRedirect for the same binary.

That's all folks.